# get ownerinfo in android settings programatically

Tags: android

Is there a way to get devicename from ownerinfo under secure settings of android. I found this way

```
String deviceName = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),   Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_OWNER_INFO);
```

but in the devlopers site there is no such constant available. Is it deprecated? i have googled but could not find the appropriate answer.

I am using android 4.1 version

Comment: Device name as in 'GT-I900' for Samsung Galaxy S2 ? Then its just `String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;`

Comment: It's not very clear what you're lookin for.  Are you looking for constants listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String ownerInfo = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_owner_info");
```

Make sure to catch [`SettingNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.SettingNotFoundException.html)

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works. Although I think ownerinfo option is available only for android versions greater than honeycomb.

Comment: Yes, and I think that complies with yourself saying _"I am using android 4.1 version"_.

Answer (score 0):

String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;