# Best way to get user-defined custom name for an Android device

Tags: android

What is the best way to get user-defined custom name of an Android device?

Some phones treat both device name and bluetooth name as the same. In these cases I could get the bluetooth name. In some phones there is a setting called `Owner Info`, under `Security->Settings`. How can I read the name from that? Or is there anything else you would suggest for my scenario? Understand that I'm not asking for the profile name from People app or the model / manufacturer of the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17585956/1893766) before:

Use

```
String ownerInfo = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        "lock_screen_owner_info");
```

Make sure to catch [`SettingNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.SettingNotFoundException.html)

### Update

As of Android 4.4.2 the owner info value is moved to lock screen database,`/data/system/locksettings.db`, to which 3rd-party apps have no read/write access. That's, there is no reliable way of reading owner info for later Android versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it is not working for Android 4.4.2. Any idea.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested with 4.4.2 and it is not working. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 1):

//this could work, but sometimes null

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name")
```

//Bluetooth name, no extra permissions

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name")
```

//p2p enabled devices could have it in here

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "wifi_p2p_device_name")
```

you always can check using this command:

```
adb shell settings list global
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running 4.4.2 and the following works:

`Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name")`

Answer (score 0):

```
String userDeviceName = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_NAME);
if(userDeviceName == null)
    userDeviceName = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_name");
```