# Get android phone name given by the user in the settings

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to get the name of the phone programatically that you can change in Settings -> About Phone?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396521/3831557)

Comment: There's a lot of phone-related (and sim card related) info you can get from the TelephonyManager API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager) but I don't see the phone name.